# Tags inside pre tag adding other formatting

Tags: html, whitespace, removing-whitespace, pre

I'm using `pre` tags to display code. I want to show some of the code as green. But when I put a `<div>` tag around the code I want green, it also does things like adds newlines, swallows spacing, et cetera. How do I get the styling to *only* change the color?

Here's my minimum example. If I have this text in an html file;

```
<pre>Some space <div style="background-color:#e6ffed;">then</div> more text.</pre>
```

and open it in chrome, it rendered as

```
Some space 
then
 more text.
```

(where the "then" line is green, as desired).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `<span>` instead, since it is an inline element.

A `<div>` is inherently a block element, so it will behave just as you see here.

You can learn more about them [here](https://medium.com/@DaphneWatson/css-display-properties-block-inline-and-inline-block-how-to-tell-the-difference-7d3a1e6e3051).